# How to use Clang to compile a big and complex project?

Tags: compilation, clang, llvm

Clang is a useful tool, but I do not how to use it to meet my needs.

```
The first question is How to use Clang to compile a big and complex project such as FFmpeg? I download the source of FFmpeg but I do not know how to compile the source.

The second question is How to get a LLVM IR file such as .ll file for a specific C file? I use the command: `clang -emit-llvm -S zmbvenc.c -o zzzzzzz1.ll`. But the result is:
```

`#include "libavutil/common.h" ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated.` 
I wonder how to generate a LLVM IR .ll file for a specific C file and ignore other related errors.

Comment: You should be able to build FFmpeg using Clang by following these instructions: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide Setting the CC environment variable to clang and CXX environment variable to clang++ should do assuming FFmpeg is compilable using Clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and one solution I found to get .ll files for a big project (as well as compile using clang) is through  [WLLVM](https://pypi.org/project/wllvm/). The only problem is that it will generate one .ll file per the whole project.

Comment: Yes, wllvm is useful! I like it.